# Switching between multiple high voltage outputs

Tags: switching

I need to verify 15 outputs from a product. All of the outputs are 230V. I want to automate this test so my idea is to connect all outputs to a PCB and then connect a multimeter and an electronic load to it. Because I have one connection to the multimeter I need to switch between the outputs to measure.

What is the best way to switch the outputs on the PCB to the multimeter?

Answer (score 2):

Mechanical relays are inexpensive and rated for mains voltage. That would be one good choice. Lifetime with such a light load would be at least 10^6 operations, which should suffice.

You could also simply buy 15 voltmeters.

Comment: 15 voltmeters might be cheaper honestly than getting relays and a PCB made lol. And you get 15x the performance.

Comment: @DKNguyen  Less than $25 for 15 and a couple spares if the offshore ones are deemed okay.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Multiple multimeters is not a solution in this case. Can’t explain the while story here, But not possible haha. Could you give an example of such mechanical switch? Because there are a lot of them

Comment: @soepblik try Panasonic JS1a and see if that works for you.

Comment: You're talking about building a scanning multimeter. Depending on the economics of the situation (would you rather hire a P.E. to sign off on safety or buy it off the shelf, is NIST traceability required, etc) it might be cheaper to just buy one from Keysight or Keithly or NI.

Answer (score 0):

Commercial polyphase meters exist for such purposes. You might be familiar with the ones in your home to measure energy consumption, but plenty can also measure voltage.

[image: Polyphase voltmeter]

Answer (score 0):

Should the product have its 15 terminals accessible, the test could be totally automated.

A test jig would first contact the 15 terminals. Then 15 relays would sequentially connect the load and digital panel meter to the 15 terminals, one terminal at a time. A pair of set-point relays, in the digital panel meter, would signal that the voltage is within range.